# How do I prevent images from moving downwards when they're replaced in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def buttonpress():
global clicks
clicks += 1
gametitle.configure(text=clicks)
if clicks == 10:
    global p, pic
    p.config(image='')
    pic = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="test2.png")
    p = tkinter.Label(root, image=pic)
    p.pack()
elif clicks == 20:
    p.config(image='')
    pic = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="test3.png")
    p = tkinter.Label(root, image=pic)
    p.pack()
```

So what I wanna do is click a button in a tkinter window with an image, and then after a certain number of 'clicks' has been reached, the image changes, but heres the problem: when the  image changes, it moves around/down the tkinter window, disrupting the position of the other widgets. I've been trying to fix this by removing the image before creating a new one, so it doesn't move anything, but I've had no such luck. Any suggestions on what to do guys?

Comment: have u made sure all the images are exactly the same size?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the old Label, instead of creating a new one. Assuming you already created a Label named "p":

```
if clicks == 10:
    pic = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="test2.png")
    p.img = pic
    p.config(image=pic)
```